# In Bayonetta, how can you kill Umbran crows?

Tags: bayonetta

So I'm staring at an Umbran crow right now, but I can't hit it. This is in chapter IV in a rainy square, while protecting Cervesa. Run at it, jump at it, shoot at it, I don't target the crow and can't hit it. What's the easiest technique to killing them?

Comment: You grab them, not kill them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem by accident after running in circles 57 times. If you approach it from one direction, it flies away from you, making it really hard to catch. If you approach from the exact opposite direction, it flies right towards you, making it an easy kill. Solved!

Comment: If this solved your issue, don’t forget to accept your own answer.